# How to properly compare strings in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Strange behavior when comparing strings in bash:

```
        if [[ $line:0:1 =~ "BSID" ]]; then
           if [ "${line:6:2}" != "$m_BSID" ]; then
              SUCCESS="fail BSID: ${line:6:2} should be $m_BSID";
              echo $SUCCESS;
           fi
        fi
```

This is what I get:

```
fail BSID: 6 should be 6
```

here variable checks:

```
Content of $line: BSID: 6 (Dolby Digital)
declare -- m_BSID="6"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there trailing spaces on the variable `$m_BSID`? Try `declare -p m_BSID` to see what it contains.

Comment: `$line:0:1` isn't doing what you think it is. You need `${line:0:1}` like you have for `${line:6:2}` in the next line.

Comment: BTW, what does $line contain?

Comment: In general, a reproducible test case would be very useful.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add detail, rather than using the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing `${line:6:2}` with `$m_BSID` in your `if` condition.

`"${line:6:2}"` will be a 2 digit string starting at index `6`, whereas `$m_BSID` is just `6`.

If you run:

```
echo "<${line:6:2}>"
```

You will get:

```
<6 >
```

that is one space after `6`, of course `"6 "` is not equal to `"6"`

You should use:

```
if [[ "${line:6:1}" != "$m_BSID" ]]; then
   SUCCESS="fail BSID: ${line:6:1} should be $m_BSID"
   echo "$SUCCESS"
fi
```